# How do I make hair particles color independent from emitter?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm quite a newbie to Blender and I'm making my first face modeling. I'm having a real hard time on the eyebrows.

I'm using a particle system to make them, but my problem is that to change the color of the particle, I have to assign a material but it looks awkward.
[image]

As you can see in the image, to make the hair brownish, the only solution I found is applying it to a material. But it does not look great.

So my question is, is there a way to change hair particle color without being obliged to assign a material?

Answer (score 4):

(this tricked also me) you need to add at leat two materials to the emitter mesh and then under the emitter setting you'll find both the materials (just select the one for the hairs)

[image]
[image]