# How can I add color to the hair particle system considering I have a vertex group that it's dedicated on the right side of his head?

Tags: particles, hair

So, I thought I could assign my vertex group to that material and therefore my particle hair system will react to that behavior. Can someone enlighten me about how to this correctly? My hair is attached to the sculpted head and has 4 vertex groups, right side, left side, scalp, and top (Referring to hair).

I´m using blender 2.91.
Thanks in advance for ur help,

[image: Hair is not coloring the hair right material, even if I assigned it to the "right vertex group"]

Comment: Hello. Not sure if the following is what you're looking for. A hair particle system can use one material slot. Which one is used you can specify in the particle settings (section Render -> Material). You also can use a texture to specify the color of the particles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/how-to-add-a-texture-to-the-emitter-surface-of-a-hair-particle-object-over-ridi

Comment: Ty for answering, I already resolved that I have to put to materials in order to recognize hair and the sculpture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem with the particle system is that yes, you have to assign in the Particle Properties>Render in the material slot the ''Emitter'' and add another material slot for your sculpture or the other object so it differentiates one from another ''Emitter'' and ''Hair'' respectively.

**Note**>(Even if you do this with one material slot, that won't work, so in your sculpture put two materials instead of one)

I think the software should make that differentiation from a default perspective, but yeah...Maybe in later versions, they will fix this. I'm using 2.91

[How do I make hair particles color independent from emitter?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170992/how-do-i-make-hair-particles-color-independent-from-emitter)