# How do I make sky and grass for scene in Blender

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting, scene, world

I already have a scene in Blender, but I have been having a hard time trying to make a world in Blender for the sky and grass... This is what my scene looks like so far:

[image]

Comment: Hello, it all depends on the style you want, the distance from the camera, the power of your computer, etc, you can use particles but it's heavy to calculate, you can use procedural texture but it can look fake, you can use image but it may look bad at certain angles, etc

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion that may help :)

You could make the sky the old classic way and cut a sphere in half:
[image]

Select the entire sphere and recalculate mesh normals to the inside:
[image]

Scale it and then UV / add image texture of a sky gradient (***make sure to disable shadows in the material!***):
[image]

Select your floor and give it a vertex group called grass:
[image]

Add particle emitter set it to hair and mess around with the settings:
[image]

Then make two materials one called floor and the other called grass:
[image]

*Assign the grass material in the render tab for the particle system check this* **[[thread]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170992/how-do-i-make-hair-particles-color-independent-from-emitter)**:

Hit that Viewport Shading button and BOOM! check out your awesome sky and grass :D
[image]

***For the sky, you could also assign the gradient texture to the emission slot in the principled BSDF shader. It'll help eliminate any shadows.***

hope this helped :D

Comment: For the sky, no need for a geometry dome, use the world's shader with a nishita sky texture or an hdri

Comment: I like how you remade my structure, you get an upvote for that :) Problem is though that I need the camera to spin around really far... I'm basically doing a remake of a Wii Boxing scene where it starts off and the narrator says "round one" but this is in the middle of a concrete road with dirt and grass around with a stadium right beside it... If you'd like to see a Wii Boxing match if you've never seen one, here is one for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97uofqy_lv8